# Beautifulsoup is not a module

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to run the following code but i get the error `Beautifulsoup is not a module`:

```
import urllib
from Beautifulsoup import BeautifulSoup
webpage = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics').read

patfinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.#)</title>')

if __name__=='__main__': main()
```

I've tried 'from bs4',
used Easy_install,
Python 2.7,
BeautifulSoup 3.2.1,
What do i do?

Comment: If you've tried installing `bs4` and it looked to have installed successfully - have you tried using `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` instead ?

Comment: i've installed BeautifulSoup. i.e easy_install BeautifulSoup. It installed properly. Now what do i do?

Comment: @JonClements it's slightly confusing because the pypi name is `beautifulsoup4`, not `bs4`

Comment: Right. So should i do easy_install beautifulsoup4 or from beautifulsoup4

Comment: @AbhishekMitra see my answer.  I laid out the process for bs3 and for bs4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual module name is `BeautifulSoup` (note case):

```
$ sudo easy_install beautifulsoup
$ python
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

For bs4:

```
$ sudo easy_install beautifulsoup4
$ python
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Hi, Im using Microsoft, but i guess the code doesn't look any different so fine. Well i tried both and neither worked. I'm using 2.7 on Win7

Comment: The difference is the case of the `S`.  You wrote `from Beautifulsoup import BeautifulSoup` but it should be `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`.  See the Difference?